# Computation of a joint distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Y = X+W$ and suppose the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ is 
$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda\cdot y} \hspace{2mm}:\hspace{2mm} 0 < x < y < \infty$$

What is the density of $W$?

I have attempted to set up 
$$ f_{W}(w) = \int_{x}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x+w}\lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda y}\phantom{ }dy\phantom{}dx $$ 
but my gut is that I am incorrect. How may I compute $f_{W}(w)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{eqnarray}F_W(w)&=&P(W\le w)\\
&=&P(Y-X\le w)\\
&=&P(Y\le w+X)\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\int_x^{w+x}\lambda^2e^{-\lambda y}dydx\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\lambda^2\left.\frac{e^{-\lambda y}}{-\lambda}\right|_{y=x}^{y=w+x}dx\\
&=&\lambda^2\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda x}-e^{-\lambda(w+x)}}{\lambda}dx\\
&=&\lambda\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\lambda w})dx\\
&=&\lambda(1-e^{-\lambda w})\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}dx\\
&=&\lambda(1-e^{-\lambda w})\frac{1}{\lambda}\\
&=&1-e^{-\lambda w}
\end{eqnarray}$

Thus $f_W(w)=\lambda e^{-\lambda w}$, $w\ge 0$, which corresponds to an exponential distribution.

Comment: Thanks. If you knew $F_{Y}(y)$, could you compute $F_{W}(w)$ from it?

Comment: The most important is knowledge of $f_{X,Y}$. If you don't know it, you can't know $F_W$, cause $W$ depends on $X$ and $Y$

Comment: A final question. How did you arrive at the limits on the double integral?